# Jenkins - Gmail SMTP secure apps security

Tags: jenkins, smtp

When I want to set build execution emails using Jenkins and SMTP server I get error with `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14` and solution for it is to switch https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps to ON.

Now, is that solution safe enough for **production**? If no then what will be **secure-enough** solution?

**thanks for help :)**

Comment: I'd send them via a third-party, like https://sendgrid.com/ or https://aws.amazon.com/ses/. Using Gmail for servers to send mail is a bad idea, in my experience. The security issues here aren't for the Jenkins server, but for you and the other Gmail users in your Google Apps install.

Comment: Thank you for the clue. Basing on your experience - why sending emails via Gmail smtp is bad idea? Lets say I would install oauth in Jenkins and then I will use Gmail for sending emails - do you think this will be good way?

Comment: Gmail is intended for and geared towards end-users, not webservers. As you're noticing, it has stuff like two-factor auth that increase users' security, but interfere with using it as a webserver's SMTP. You'll also find that it has daily limits on the number of outgoing emails, which you may run into fairly easily. Setting up something like Sendgrid is much, much easier in the long run.